# Github Job API - Get total amount of positions

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, github-api

I've built an Angular app that replicates : https://jobs.github.com/positions.api

Unfortunately, they provide only 50 available positions per page,

so in order to fetch the next 50 jobs, I have to add "?page=X" to another GET request.

Therefore, my GET response returns only the first page.

Is there any way to fetch the total amount of positions by using only 1 GET request or by any other way?

Much Appreciated!

**My code:**

**Service.ts**

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class PositionserviceService {

  // uri = 'https://jobs.github.com/positions'

  constructor(public http: HttpClient) { }

  getAllPositions(){
    return this.http.get('https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://jobs.github.com/positions.json');
  }


  getNextPage4(page){
    return this.http.get(`https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://jobs.github.com/positions.json?page=${page}`);

  }

}
```

**Componnent.ts file:**

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { PositionserviceService } from '../services/positionservice.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-showallpositions',
  templateUrl: './showallpositions.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./showallpositions.component.css']
})
export class ShowallpositionsComponent implements OnInit {
  positions: Object
  positions4: Object
  isCollapsed = true;
  
  constructor(public positionService: PositionserviceService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.positionService.getAllPositions().subscribe(data => {
      this.positions = data;
      console.log(this.positions)
    })
    // this.getPage4()

  }


  // getPage4(){
  //   this.positionService.getNextPage4().subscribe(data4 => {
  //     this.positions4 = data4;
  //     console.log("Page 4:", this.positions4)
  //   })
  // }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The [docs](https://jobs.github.com/api) don't say anything about this. I think a loop that fetches all the jsons and merges them would be a possible solution, even though I wouldn't recommend making so many calls to the api.

If you're looking for just the **number** of positions, you could make the loop request the list for each page, until it crashes. If you add a counter to the loop and multiply its result by 50, you're getting pretty close to the actual number.

I found some extra info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29518253/how-to-get-number-of-result-pages-for-the-data-fetched-from-github-api-for-a-req). This user suggests that you can get the url for the last page from your request.

You can also just follow [this link](https://jobs.github.com/positions) and it will show the total amount of jobs on top.

Comment: I tried something like this;

service.ts:
  getAllPoistions2(page){
    return this.http.get(`https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://jobs.github.com/positions.json?page=${page}`);
  }

component.ts:
  getAllPositions(){
    for(let i = 1; i<=4; i++){
      this.positionService.getAllPoistions2(i).subscribe((data) => {
        this.positions = data
        console.log("All Positions:", this.positions)
      })
    }

but this.positions is equal to the "data" of the last loop...
how can I improve that so "this.position" will hold all positions?
By using an array maybe?